# Regular calls to Android garbage collector (GC_FOR_ALLOC) in fairly basic app

Tags: java, android, memory-management, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I have written a fairly simple program where I am collecting wifi signal strengths and storing them in `ArrayLists`.

The scanning of wifi access points and storage of received values takes place in a `Runnable` which I call with a `ScheduledExecutorService`.

When my program runs on a Nexus 4, I seem to get regular calls to `GC_FOR_ALLOC`. This does not occur when I run my program on an HTC One M8. The calls occur quite frequently. The heap size seems to increase to about 16mb before stopping.

I am calling a `class` method which declares a `List` and `ArrayList` on each run. Is this considered bad practice and would this have an impact on memory usage?

Does anyone have any tips they can provide on how to go about solving this issue?

Here is my `Runnable` code. The `wifiObject` is the object on which I am calling my `scanWifi` method:

```
final Wifi wifiObject = new Wifi((WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE));


    periodicTask = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : AccessPoints.entrySet()) {
                int APNoToBeSent = 0;

                try {
                    wifiObject.scanWifi(entry.getKey(), accessPointMeanRSSArrayList, accessPointRSSFrequencyArrayList);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                ++APNoToBeSent;
            }
        }

    };
```

Here is where I am declaring the `ArrayList` and `List` in the `scanWifi` method:

```
public void scanWifi(String APName, ArrayList<Integer> accessPointMeanRSSArrayList, ArrayList<Integer> accessPointRSSFrequencyArrayList) {


    ArrayList<Integer> tempRSSArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    boolean AP_found = false;


    WifiManager myWifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo myWifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();

    for (int x = 1; x <= 50; ++x){
        if (wifiManager.startScan() == true) {
            List<ScanResult> WifiScanResults = wifiManager.getScanResults();

            int APsFound = WifiScanResults.size();
```

Comment: 16mb sounds pretty high for just `List` and `ArrayList`. What type of object is stored in those? Do you have a estimate of how many classes get created?

Comment: *I seem to get regular calls to GC_FOR_ALLOC. This does not occur when I run my program on an HTC One M8*, GC implementation will be different for different machines, So, I wouldn't worry much about this. Show us the code where you are declaring `List/ArrayList`.

Comment: @MiroMarkarian only one object (wifiObject) is created. The List is storing wifi scan result info and the ArrayList is storing Integers.

Comment: @TheLostMind is right. GC could be configured differently on devices.

Comment: Use DDMS.  Inspect the heap and see what you are putting on there.